# REACT JS - Not able to set the state of an empty object to the response from the api

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

I am fetching json data from my local api but can't seem to assign it to the `err` state.

```
const [err, setErr] = useState({});
const host = "http://localhost:9000";

const addNote = async (obj) => {
        
  const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/addnote`, {
      method : 'POST',
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'auth-token' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY3MTQ0ODMyOH0.sNTvl4L9HFaGPOmuSKpJMu418axsUmgDib-94ked3lQ'},
      body : JSON.stringify(obj)
  });
  const data = await res.json();

  console.log(data);

  setErr(data);
  
  console.log(err);
}
```

On logging data I get => `{title:{msg :''}, description:{msg:''}}`
On logging err I get => `{}`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you edit the question to be more descriptive, please?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are not seeing what you're expecting when you do `console.log(err)` and you expect to see `data` inside. `setErr` might take some time to update and you might not be able to see it immediately. Please try to do your `console.log(err)` outside the `addNote` function in the component itself.
This way when the component re-renders because of the state change you will be able to see the updated state.

Answer (score 1):

useState() hook is asynchronous and will not reflect the update immediately. The value get's update in the next render and you can verify that with useEffect hook as shown below

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(err) // prints the updated value
}, [err])
```

If you want the update to reflect immediately, you can use useRef() instead of useState().

**Updated answer**

I don't recommend using useRef() as it would force the updates between the renders which in turn effects the performance. If you want the errors to be displayed based on backend response, then don't render the component until you receive a response. Refer below code snippet

```
const [err, setErr] = useState({});
const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(false);
const host = "http://localhost:9000";
const addNote = async (obj) => {
  setIsDataLoading(true); // update loading state
  const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/addnote`, {
     method : 'POST',
     headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'auth-token' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY3MTQ0ODMyOH0.sNTvl4L9HFaGPOmuSKpJMu418axsUmgDib-94ked3lQ'}, 
     body : JSON.stringify(obj)
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  setErr(data);
  setIsDataLoading(false); // update loading state
  console.log(data);
}
return (
   {
      isDataLoading ? <Loading /> : <YourComponent /> // if isDataLoading is true render some loading symbol else render your actual component.
   } 
)
```

Comment: thnx alot bro... can u plz update the code via useRef()... i dont know how to do that.... actually i need to validate the title and description fields....so when i get an error from the backend, i need to assign that error response object  to the "err" and then use err to reflect those error msges in the frontend....but i m not able to assign so not able to render those error msges... plz help... thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
const [err, setErr] = useState({});
const host = "http://localhost:9000";

const addNote = async (obj) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/addnote`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token":
          "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY3MTQ0ODMyOH0.sNTvl4L9HFaGPOmuSKpJMu418axsUmgDib-94ked3lQ",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      // need to check object and set error as per object mappig
      setErr(res.data);
    }
  } catch {
    setErr('Api not workoing');
  }

  console.log(err);
};
```

Comment: Thnk u soo much!!!